# Complex Inner Product Space always zero

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inner-products

I'm trying to solve the problem below:

Let $(X,\langle\,\cdot\,\rangle)$ be a complex inner product space. Suppose $x \in X$ and $Y$ is a linear subspace of $X$ such that $\operatorname{Re} \langle x,y\rangle = 0$ for all $y\in Y$. Show that in fact $\langle x,y\rangle = 0$ for all $y \in Y$.

This is for an assignment so I'm not looking for a full solution as I want to understand how to do this in the future! A hint would be very welcome though.

Comment: $Y$ is a subspace. Therefore every complex multiple of an element of $Y$ is also in $Y$ and must satisfy the same condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\langle x, iy \rangle$. What's the real part of that expression?

Comment: $<x,iy> = <-iy,x>=-i<y,x>$ so the real part is zero so if $y \in Y$ then this satisfies the given condition. So then I just need to show the complex part is zero also?

Comment: You're getting there, Note that if $y \in Y$, then $iy \in Y$ and $\frac{1}{i}y \in Y$ because $Y$ is a linear subspace. Hint: write $\langle x, y \rangle = a + bi$. What do you know about $a$? What does my hint tell you about $b$?

Comment: @user280598 if you think you've got it you can simply post an answer, then we can check whether it's solid or not and the question is answered properly